# Jupyter R: The procedure entry point inflateReset2 could not be located in the dynamic link library zlib1.dll

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to get my company to adopt Jupyter as a standard interface for R on Windows however after installing it and opening a brand new notebook I get this error message that doesn't go away:

```
the procedure entry point inflateReset2 could not be located in the dynamic link library zlib1.dll
```

I did a google search and tried installing [gtk3 for Windows](https://github.com/tschoonj/GTK-for-Windows-Runtime-Environment-Installer/releases) (which in itself loses marks in my books as it brings up a Symantic warning that they don't know enough about this file which wouldn't look good to the average business user) however that has not helped..although I restarted Jupyter but not my laptop after installing it (as it's currently in the middle of running something long).

What is a practical business-friendly solution to this error message?